# Headphones Occasionally Stop Working

Tags: audio

My headphones go silent sometimes. Today it occurred, and I changed headphones. Not only that, but I cannot change the volume, and all the videos I'm watching endlessly buffers. The windows button does not work, so to restart my computer I needed to restart by holding the power off button. I don't know what is causing this. The keyboard also holds down keys when I press down on them for some time.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. This is nowhere near enough information. Please provide the make and model of the earphones you are using, as well as that of the computer, and the operating system you use.

Answer (score 0):

> ...so to restart my computer I needed to restart by holding the power
> off button

This is not at all normal.

Get the manufacturer's Driver Update App.  Install that and run it.

Pay particular attention to BIOS and then the rest of the driver updates.

Start there and see if this is a driver update (likely I think) or a Windows problem.

If you update all the drivers, and still have the issue, consider running a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: Oh. I actually reset my whole computer and reinstalled the programs (although the shortcut is gone and I don't know how to recover it). Does that still work?

Comment: A Reset should work and fix shortcuts. You should have your Windows button back. Did you update drivers?

Comment: I'm not sure if I did.